# How to fetch elasticsearch api with auth

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, fetch

i try to fetch elastic api using javascript with basic authentication, but there is error show that request header field authorization is not allowed by acccess-control-allow-headers, is it something wrong with the elasticsearch api or the wrong is on my code? i already setting enable cors on elastic, i tried curl to get elastic data with auth and it works, does the fetch code is wrong?

the console error :
[image]

the fetch code :

```
        fetch('http://192.168.150.220:9900/', {method:'GET', 
        headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('em_user:3md@t@2o22')}})
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use fetch from your browser, you will have to allow cross-origin requests in the ElasticSearch configuration:

```
 http.cors.enabled : true
 http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
 http.cors.allow-methods: OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
 http.cors.allow-headers: X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type,Content-Length,Authorization
 http.cors.allow-credentials: true
```

Source:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.2/modules-network.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-enterprise/current/ece-configure-cors.html